# Image not appearing when sharing URL via Facebook

Tags: facebook, image, share

I'm preparing to launch a new site, http://www.careerclaim.com, and if I share the URL via FB only the URL displays, not the logo and title.

I've entered the URL in FB's debugger and it returns:
Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.

Please help!  Thank you!!!

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but it looks like your server isn't sending data to the Facebook crawler.

Comment: what would prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to the HTTPS version of your page, but your og:url meta element states that the version using just HTTP was the “real” one – and that leads to an endless redirect circle, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.careerclaim.com%2F

Comment: I updated the og:URL to <meta property="og:URL" content="https://www.careerclaim.com" /> but my image, https://www.careerclaim.com/images/logo.png, still isn't showing...